# Change title of untitled tab in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, titlebar, vscode-extensions

I'm building a VS Code extension which includes changing the name/title of `untitled-1` tab (unsaved file).
I tried running the below code in debugger console of extension but it didn't reflect in the editor:

```ts
vscode.workspace.textDocuments[0].fileName="myFile"
```

Is it not possible or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible - if you check out the source code for [the API definition in `vscode.d.ts`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/1.31.0/src/vs/vscode.d.ts#L105), you'll see that `fileName` is declared as `readonly`:

```typescript
export interface TextDocument {
    // ...
    readonly fileName: string;
    // ...
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the `readonly` attribute isn't reflected in the [API docs on the website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_a-nametextdocumentaspan-classcodeitem-id38textdocumentspan).

Comment: this is sad. Is there any way I can convince them to make the field mutable?

Comment: Seems unlikely, considering all the other properties are read-only as well. Besides, I doubt think `fileName` directly corresponds to what ends up being shown in the tab title.

Comment: oh so there's a possibility that tab title is not taken from filename? Could you please confirm

Comment: Seems that ultimately, [`getPathLabel()`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/1.15.1/src/vs/base/common/labels.ts#L31) is responsible for the editor titles, which indeed uses the file name.

Answer (score 13):

It is still (Q1 2020) not possible, but the next VSCode 1.42 will [name its Untitled editors differently](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/23dfcc98bf6b78a2530afb2efe297fd9b60d77d7/release-notes/v1_42.md#untitled-editor-improvements).

> Untitled editors in VS Code are text buffers that have not yet been saved to disk.
>   You can leave them open for as long as you like and all text content is stored and restored between restarts.
>
> Untitled editors were given generic names such as `Untitled-1` and counting upwards.
>   **In this release, untitled editors will use the content of the first line of the document for the editor title**, and include the generic name as part of the description:

[image: https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_42/untitled-title2.gif]

> Note: If the first line is empty or does not contain any words, the title will fall back to `Untitled_*` as before.

So while you cannot set the title yourself (still `readonly fileName`), technically... changing the *first line* of that file would be enough to change the title of said "Untitled" editor.

---

With [VSCode 1.43 (Q1 2020)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/7415295786638654d08e2a88c41e737b803edb89/release-notes/v1_43.md#untitled-editors), a new setting **`workbench.editor.untitled.labelFormat`** allows to control whether untitled editors should use the contents as title or not.
Possible values are `content` or `name`.
Configure '`workbench.editor.untitled.labelFormat`': '`name`' to get the previous behavior back where untitled editors would have a short title, such as `Untitled-1`.

Comment: that's exactly what I was trying to build the extension for.

Answer (score 0):

This mainly happens if we create a new file in the OPEN EDITORS section, thus they appear as unsaved. To prevent this, create a folder for storing your files, and then in that folder, create your new file then it will show options to name it, also you can add a file type extension like .cpp.
TIP: vsc-rename-files extension to rename your files.