# How to get an unsaved file in VS Code to use the first line as the title?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm coming from Sublime, where if you open a new file, it will use the first line of this file as the name of the tab. How can I accomplish the same in VS Code without saving the file? Currently it makes it annoying to remember what is what if I'm trying to do something like a quick diff or if I'm taking some notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not possible due to restrictions in the API.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876887/change-title-of-untitled-tab-in-visual-studio-code).