# PHP Language Mode is no longer an option

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

"PHP" has been removed from my VS as an option for language modes.

I have uninstalled and reinstall vs code multiple times deleting all extensions and cleaning all local configurations.

OS: Windows 10

VS Code Version: 1.22.1

Comment: have you checked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775551/how-to-manually-set-language-for-syntax-highlighting-in-visual-studio-code
? I am running the latest official version and can find it

Comment: That is how you change the langauge mode, that is exactly where I went to discover that PHP is missing and is not an option.

Comment: Can you expand your question with information about OS, VS Code version and information about what you tried. 
On my Ubuntu with version 1.22.1 I can find PHP without problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to VS Code github this is a known bug in VS Code version 1.22.1 for Windows and is fixed in the upcoming version.

[Link to the issue.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47110)

Comment: Thank you so much, i spent a while looking for the issue but couldn't find it, there are just too many issues.