# How to automatically set language for syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, azure-pipelines

This is the inverse of [How to manually set language for syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775551/how-to-manually-set-language-for-syntax-highlighting-in-visual-studio-code)

Basically what I'd want is something similar in VI where it will detect some string that would specify the format of a file specifically for Azure Pipelines

```yaml
# --language-mode: azure-pipelines
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

you can write an extension that uses `vscode.languages.setTextDocumentLanguage`
like the extension [Change Language Mode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.change-language-mode).

Add a hook for document change and open and analyse the content and search for a particular string and set the mode if it is different.

Configure the strings to search for and the language id to set in the settings