# How to enable HTML syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code on an .ntl template file?

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code

I was previously using Sublime Text editor and `HTML` syntax highlighting worked out of the box for `.ntl` files.

I have just installed Visual Studio Code and it is not applying syntax highlighting to an `.ntl` file.

This answer shows how to manually apply a specific syntax highlighting to the code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30776845

But I am just wondering how you can associated `.ntl` files with `HTML` syntax highlighting.

For context, the `.ntl` file is used as a simple template engine in an `Node.js/Express` application, see:

https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/developing-template-engines.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> >
`Change Language Mode` > `Configure File Association for '.ntl'...` > `HTML`.

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228725/1063287).

Also see:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_language-identifier